# Looking to add the "Log On as a service" right to an account via the command line

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-command-prompt

I am looking to make a user from the command line with minimal rights to run a service. cmd.exe or powershell.exe are both options, but cmd.exe is preferable. So far I got this:

```
net user /add testUser227e5910-d1ac-11df-bd3b-0800200c9a66
net localgroup Users testUser /delete
```

The next step is to grant this user the right of "Log On As a Service". I can't seem to figure out how to do this. This is for a blog article, so I want a solution that applies to Windows XP, 2003, 2008, 2008R2, Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: Maybe possible using those commands in remote computer ?

Answer (score 8):

You need to install ntrights from the Windows resource kit : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276

`ntright +r SeServiceLogonRight -u testUser`

Comment: I'd prefer something that was built in, but if no one provides a better answer I'll mark that right.

Comment: There is nothing built in - if there was Microsoft wouldn't provide this in the resource kit ;-)

Comment: Ok I can't install that on windows 2008 or Windows 7. What do I do there?

Comment: You can use the 2003 version : http://serverfault.com/questions/141168/ntrights-equivalent-replacement-for-server-2008

Comment: I'm about to write my own command line utility to do this. Either that or I'll just implement this feature request in mongod, the program that lead me down this rabbit hole. http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1227

Comment: How can I do this task in remote computer ?